# Preparing app for submission

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

What are some things you need to do when preparing your app for submission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register with Apple and then read the [Prepare for App Submission](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/) checklist from Apple (if you have yet to register, the [App Store Resource Center](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/) lists the available online guides). This page also walks you through the process so that you'll know what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

Create the new app at itunesconnect.apple.com . 
Clean all build targets and build it fresh. 
Make sure you have your provisioning profiles installed in the Keychain so you can sign it. Upload it through XCode's Organizer.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to also run it through the App Scanner to make sure that you have not accidentally used private API - thus preventing a rejection some time after submission.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35448/app-scanner

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of checklists available out there for people publishing iOS apps. Here's one i found after a quick google search:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/47462278/iOS-App-Submission-Checklist

Comment: This document is missing pages... not much help without them.

Comment: this link requires a paid membership.